# Inheritance classes inside another inheritance classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I have problem with inheritance in Java. I will use army example:
I have one class base:

```
public class Soldier {
    Squad squad;

    public Soldier(Squad _squad) {
        squad = _squad;
    }
    //and some methods, that use squad 
}
```

and I have:

```
public class Archer extends Soldier {
    public Archer(ArcherSquad _squad) {
        super(_squad);
    }
    //some new methods, some override 
}
```

and:

```
public class Warrior extends Soldier {
    public Warrior(WarriorSquad _squad) {
        super(_squad);
    }
    //some new methods, some override 
}
```

and my squads look like:

```
Squad;
ArcherSquad extends Squad(some new methods);
WarriorSquad extends Squad(some new methods);
```

Now I want to access to methods in `ArcherSquad` from `Archer`. How can I change code without broking anything?

Comment: It's hard to tell what issue you're running into. Can you be more specific? Can you show the methods you're trying to call but can't?

Comment: The only glitch i found is that you are receiving _squad as an argument and giving super(squad) instead of super(_squad) to the super class constructor. Since Archersquad is a subclass of squad you should be able to access its methods IMHO.

Comment: In ArcherSquad I have `arrowStrike()` metod and I don't have access in Archer, because Java say that Squad don't have this method. And it's normal, but i want to refactor my stucture to be able to do this.

Comment: @Saraiva yes, It was my mistake in coping :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move the reference to the squad up to `ArcherSquad`

```
public abstract class Soldier {
    // force subclass supply some squad
    protected abstract Squad getSquad();
    public void someMethod() {
        Squad squad = getSquad();
        // do something with it.
    }
}

public class Archer extends Soldier {
    private ArcherSquad archerSquad;
    public Archer(ArcherSquad _squad) {
        archerSquad = _squad;
    }
    @Override
    protected Squad getSquad() {
        return archerSquad;
    }
    ...
}
```

or you can turn `Soldier` into a generic class

```
public class Soldier<T extends Squad> {
    protected T squad;

    public Soldier(T _squad) {
        this.squad = _squad;
    }

    public void someMethod() {
        Squad squad = this.squad;
        // do something with it.
    }
}

public class Archer extends Soldier<ArcherSquad> {

    public Archer(ArcherSquad _squad) {
        super(_squad);
    }

    public void someMethodUsingArcherSquad() {
        ArcherSquad as = squad;
    }
    // some new methods, some override
}
```